Mismatch in tensor dimensions in BayesianFPN with Reinforcement Learning
I am implementing a computer vision project. I have used an FPN (with ResNet50 backbone) and BayesianFPN in this project. This network is under a Reinforcement Learning Agent. Upon implementation, it throws me a
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (256) at non-singleton dimension 3


What made the code throw this error?
Is it because of the mismatch in the training image (RGB image) and validation image (Binary Mask)?
Is there some internal dimension change I am missing?

Below is the code. This is the BayesianFPNwithRL class I want to implement.
I tried reshaping the weights tensor. It did not work. Even unsqueezing or expanding it did not.
FOR REFERENCE:

RGB image dimensions - 1280x720px;
Binary mask dimensions: 1280x720px

# Bayesian FPN with RL
class BayesianFPNWithRL(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, backbone_with_fpn, rl_agent, dropout_p=0.2):
        super(BayesianFPNWithRL, self).__init__()
        self.backbone_with_fpn = backbone_with_fpn
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout_p)
        self.rl_agent = rl_agent

    def forward(self, x, mc_samples=10, train_rl=False):
    
        fpn_outputs = self.backbone_with_fpn(x)
        keys = list(fpn_outputs.keys())
        features = [fpn_outputs[key] for key in keys]
    
    
        common_size = features[0].shape[2:] 
        features = [F.interpolate(f, size=common_size, mode="nearest") for f in features]
    
    
        if not self.training:
            sampled_features = []
            for _ in range(mc_samples):
                sampled_features.append([self.dropout(f) for f in features])
            features = [
                torch.mean(torch.stack([sample[i] for sample in sampled_features]), dim=0)
                for i in range(len(features))
            ]
    
        global_features = [f.mean(dim=(2, 3)) for f in features]  
        rl_input = torch.cat(global_features, dim=1) 
    
        action, log_prob = self.rl_agent.select_action(rl_input)
    
    
        weights = torch.zeros(len(features), device=x.device)
        weights[action] = 1.0  
    
    
        selected_features = sum(w * f for w, f in zip(weights, features))
    
        if train_rl:
            return selected_features, log_prob
        return selected_features

if __name__ == "__main__":

    resnet = resnet50(weights = ResNet50_Weights.DEFAULT)
    return_layers = {
        'layer1': '0',
        'layer2': '1',
        'layer3': '2',
        'layer4': '3'
    }
    in_channels_list = [256, 512, 1024, 2048]
    out_channels = 256
    backbone_with_fpn = BackboneWithFPN(resnet, return_layers, in_channels_list, out_channels)
    
    
    rl_agent = RLAgent(input_dim=1280, hidden_dim=512, action_space=4)
    
    
    bayesian_fpn_rl = BayesianFPNWithRL(backbone_with_fpn, rl_agent).to('cuda')
    
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(bayesian_fpn_rl.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
    
    
    for epoch in range(10):  
        for images, ground_truth_masks in dataloader:
            images, ground_truth_masks = images.to('cuda'), ground_truth_masks.to('cuda')
    
    
            model_output, log_prob = bayesian_fpn_rl(images, train_rl=True)
    
            predicted_mask = (model_output > 0.5).int()
    
            reward = compute_reward(predicted_mask, ground_truth_masks)
    
            loss = rl_loss(log_prob, reward)
    
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    
            print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, Reward: {reward:.4f}")


